# SwiftUI: alert does not work in .onChange()'s action

Tags: swiftui

I'm using `PhotosPicker` to let the user pick some photos. Afterwards, I want to display an alert asking the user to confirm or cancel.

I have code like this:

```
PhotosPicker(selection: $photosPicked, matching: .images) {
    Label("Pick Photos", systemImage: "photo.badge.plus.fill").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.onChange(of: photosPicked, {
    // This code is executed but it does not display the alert
    showConfirmation = true
})
.alert("Are you sure?", isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
    Button("Yes") { }
    Button("No", role: .cancel) { }
```

However, this is not working. I scratched my head a little bit, and I suspect this is what happened. The action in `.onChange` is executed right after the photos are picked, but *before* the picker sheet is dismissed. When the picker sheet is dismissed, the alert dialog somehow disappears with it.

It smells like a bug in SwiftUI. Does anyone have a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the alert does not show while the PhotosPicker is still displayed.
 Try using `DispatchQueue.main.async { showConfirmation = true }`
 and if need be add a delay `...asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)`. Also seems to work using `Task { showConfirmation = true }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var photosPicked: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
    @State private var showConfirmation = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker(selection: $photosPicked, matching: .images) {
                Label("Pick Photos", systemImage: "photo.badge.plus.fill")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .onChange(of: photosPicked) { _, _ in
                // Use asyncAfter to introduce a delay and allow the sheet to be dismissed
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    showConfirmation = true
                }
            }
            .alert("Are you sure?", isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
                Button("Yes") {
                    // Handle 'Yes' button action
                }
                Button("No", role: .cancel) {
                    // Handle 'No' button action
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. So it sounds like updating @State variables need to happen on the UI thread (or whatever term SwiftUI uses) and .onChange() does not run on that thread.

Comment: @DelingRen .onChange() modifier in SwiftUI runs on the same thread where the observed value changes. If the observed value changes on the main thread, the .onChange() closure will also be executed on the main thread. But in above case alert might be triggering too quick without you able to see it so for UI related responsiveness and to avoid unexpected behaviours we Dispatch the changes to main thread for consistent UI updates.

Answer (score 1):

`.onChange` is for external actions not updating other states and we are supposed to group related states into a custom struct, e.g. something like this:

```
struct Content {
    var photosPicked: [PhotosPickerItem] = [] {
        didSet {
            showConfirmation = true
        }
    }
    var showConfirmation = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var content = Content()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker(selection: $content.photosPicked, matching: .images) {
                Label("Pick Photos", systemImage: "photo.badge.plus.fill")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .alert("Are you sure?", isPresented: $content.showConfirmation) {
                Button("Yes") {
                    // Handle 'Yes' button action
                }
                Button("No", role: .cancel) {
                    // Handle 'No' button action
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```